# Script to check if ssh connection is success

Tags: shell

I have 100 servers. From the first server, i want to check if ssh connection from this first server to other servers is OK or not.

If OK, then it would ouput OK, if not, it would output Failed.

I did some setup before with hostname and key pair, so basically i just enter:

```
ssh name-server
```

Then i would know the result.

For example

Failed case:

```
[centos@tony]$ ssh server1
Last login: Thu Aug  9 17:01:21 2018 from 172.21.11.5
Connection to server1 closed.
```

OK case:

```
[centos@tony]$ ssh server1
Last login: Thu Aug  9 17:01:21 2018 from 172.21.11.5
```

I have a file list.txt include all hostname of all servers.

```
server1
server2
...
```

My script not worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat /home/centos/list.txt); do
result=`ssh i | grep closed`
if [ -z "$result" ] ; then
  echo "OK"
fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ssh $i` instead of `ssh i`

Comment: Also "Connection to server1 closed." is probably written into stderr.
use this:
`ssh $i |& grep closed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man ssh`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

So just execute a simple command on the remote server and check for its success. The simplest command imaginable is `true` (which just returns `0` / success):

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in $(cat /home/centos/list.txt)
do
  if ssh $server "true"
  then
    echo "Server $server: OK"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @TheOne: Generally speaking, a script should *never* try to "parse" the output of a command. The user might run a different locale (and suddenly the output of the command isn't English anymore). Or the user might run on a different platform, where the command used is e.g. not GNU xyz but BSD xyz or a busybox executable with a different output. The next version of the command might change the output. The user might have aliased the command to produce different output. If at all possible, use the exit status of a command.