# How can I check if my connection to MySQL is using SSH or not?

Tags: mysql, delphi, ssh

I am using a new install of MyDac 10.1.3 and Securebridge 9.2 in Delphi 2009 to connect to a remote MySQL database hosted on a shared server (at JustHostMe) that they claim allows SSH. I do not have access to the server itself so cannot run any admin type commands, just SQL. I can connect normally using port 3306 but wanted to do so using SSH.

I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/ssh.htm), made my private and public keys, transferred my public key to the server and authorised it using cpanel, made a new database user especially for this tutorial. The tutotal says to use a TCRSSHIOHandler but there isn't one on the palette so I used TMySSHIOHandler instead which seems to be the same thing.

The port in the ScSSHClient is set to 22 as in the tutorial but the port on the TMyConnection will only accept 3306 (22 won't connect when I test it).

Essentially, the test application runs, connects to the database and shows the result of the SQL `SHOW STATUS` (which I put in the query as a test).

**My question though is simply this,**

How can I check if the connection is using SSH or not?

Bearing in mind I am running a Delphi application connected to a shared server to which I don't have admin access.

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762086/script-to-check-if-ssh-connection-is-success) but that seems to assume I have direct access to the server.

In case anyone asks to see the code for this minimalist application, the whole lot is simply

```
unit U_frmMain;
// see https://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/ssh.htm

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ScSSHClient, ScBridge, StdCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, DB, MemDS, DBAccess,
  MyAccess, CRVio, CRSSLIOHandler, MySSLIOHandler, CRSSHIOHandler,
  MySSHIOHandler;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MyConnection1: TMyConnection;
    MyQuery1: TMyQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    ScFileStorage1: TScFileStorage;
    ScSSHClient1: TScSSHClient;
    MySSHIOHandler1: TMySSHIOHandler;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
MyQuery1.open;
end;

end.
```

Comment: it's not that easy, you must setup a ssh tunnel to your mysql server on the cloud host. You must have admin access to set this up. In the Devart article you linked they show how to do this on a windows server, but I guess the JustHostMe will be a linux box...

Comment: mysql workbench and setting on tcp over ssh and see if you can connect to your myql server and youi have to put as **ssh host name 127.0.0.1**

Comment: and of course you could start wireshark and see if password are transported in cleartext

Comment: @whosrdaddy. Thanks you, I spotted the setting up a window server in part 2 of the article but assumed that was only if I wasn't using securebridge but openssl instead as they say. JustHostMe claim that the server is SSH ready and cpanel has a feature to install and authenticate the public certificate. That would seem to suggest admin have done their bit? Is it the case that attempting to connect using SSH tunnelling  on a server that hasn't been set up for it will connect anyway in plain text or would it just fail to connect? That would be a clue as to whether its working or not.

Comment: The tunnel would be advertised on a certain port (not port 22, that would give you access to the linux shell and not port 3306 as that is the standard MySQL port), I looked at the JustHostMe docs and nothing is being said about SSH tunnels so assume this is not setup. You can always verify with a SSH client like Putty or use Wireshark as mentioned above.

Comment: FYI In the Devart article, they setup the tunnel on port 3307.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for all the info, and for taking the trouble to check with JustHostMe. Wireshark showed plain text as I expected it would (shame, it would have been more useful if the connection gave an error, at least then I would have known). Connection on port 3307 was actively refused. I'll get on to JustHostMe and see what they say, what port to use etc.